# How to remove the space between the pictures

Tags: java, android, bundle, image

This is my code for adding a picture on the text,  but there is a big
 space between the pictures. How can I remove the space and let the
 pictures be next to each other with out messing up what it originally does. 
Can you tell me were should I modify my code?

```
te2.setText(" ");
String t = te1.getText().toString();

final SpannableStringBuilder builder1 = new SpannableStringBuilder(
                    te1.getText());

            char[] aa = t.toString().toCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) {

                switch (aa[i]) {

                case 's':

                    while (builder1.toString().indexOf("s") > -1) {
                        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(
                                getBaseContext(), R.drawable.a1);
                        int pos = builder1.toString().indexOf("s");
                        builder1.replace(pos, pos + 1, "$");
                        builder1.setSpan(imageSpan, pos, pos + 1,
                                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    }

                    te2.setText(builder1);

                    break;

                case 'g':

                    while (builder1.toString().indexOf("g") > -1) {
                        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(
                                getBaseContext(), R.drawable.a2);
                        int pos = builder1.toString().indexOf("g");
                        builder1.replace(pos, pos + 1, "$");
                        builder1.setSpan(imageSpan, pos, pos + 1,
                                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    }
                    te2.setText(builder1);

                    break;
                case 'v':

                    while (builder1.toString().indexOf("v") > -1) {
                        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(
                                getBaseContext(), R.drawable.a2);
                        int pos = builder1.toString().indexOf("v");
                        builder1.replace(pos, pos + 1, "$");
                        builder1.setSpan(imageSpan, pos, pos + 1,
                                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    }
                    te2.setText(builder1);

                    break;

                } // / end of loop

            } // end of switch

        }
```

Comment: I think you have the end of loop and end of switch interchanged.

Comment: @cyril-pangilinan do you have any suggestion in how to fix it !?